# Custom keyboard auto capitalization

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, autocapitalize

I would like to adopt the TextField's AutocapitalizationType settings to the custom keyboard. How do I know when to capitalize the keyboard while typing?

I searched for solutions and examples, I looked through the Apple Developer Documentation, but I can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to analyze the text around the current insertion point and capitalize accordingly.

- `.none`: Simple, never capitalize.
- `.words`: If the character before the insertion point is a space and maybe a hyphen. Also if at the start.
- `.sentences`: If the insertion point is preceded by white space and end of sentence punctuation (period, question mark, exclamation, etc.) or if at the start.
- `.allCharacters`: Simple - always capitalize.

Of course these rules may vary based on language.

You can see some of the text before the insertion point using `textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput`.

Some of the answers found at [Swift: Split String into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904253/swift-split-string-into-sentences) might prove helpful.

There is also [iOS Custom Keyboard Extension auto capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571366/ios-custom-keyboard-extension-auto-capitalization) which has some ideas as well.